# System.TypeException: You are already logged in

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am trying to create portal user by using:
`Site.createPortalUser(u, account.Id,'Sep@2012',true);` method.
But i am  getting the type exception:

> "System.TypeException: You are already logged in".

I am testing with system admin profile. 
Could any one please suggest what to do to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are testing the community by Admin profile.

Solution is you should open the community page on an incognito browser so that you are accessing the page as a real Guest user.